# SSDT Build Error SQL71501/71502 When referencing metadata generated objects

Tags: sql-server, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

In our SSDT project we have a number of objects (tables, views, procs, functions) created as part of post deployment script using metadata.

The problem we have is that some of the non metadata created objects fail to build when they reference those metadata created ones with `SQL71501` or `SQL71502` errors, obviously.  As what they are trying to reference haven't actually been created, or exist in the SSDT project.

> SQL71501: View: [dbo].[whatever] has an unresolved reference to object
> [schema].[function].[column]

> SQL71502: Procedure: [dbo].[proc_name] has an unresolved reference to
> object [schema].[table_name.[column]

At the moment we get around this by creating "stubs" of those objects.eg.

```
-- stub implementation of metadata-managed object for SSDT

CREATE FUNCTION [schema].[functionName] (
  @param DATETIME
) RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

SELECT
  NULL AS [RecordId]
, CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) AS [FromDateTime]
, CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS [name]
...
WHERE 0 = 1
```

This works, however, it sort of defeats the object of metadata created objects when we have to create dummy versions of those object to allow the SSDT to build.

My question is, are there alternatives ways around this?

Comment: You can't reference objects that you create in pre-script. Why do you need it?

Comment: like I said in the question, it sort of defeats the object of metadata created objects when we have to create dummy versions of those object to allow the SSDT to build. I wanted to know if there's an alternative approach. @DmitrijKultasev

Comment: More out of curiosity, what is an example of one of these metadata created objects? Specifically, a metadata-defined table is beyond my imagination (the others being code-only I can conceive of perhaps going against an unknown plurality of tables).

Comment: @BenThul Define the table structure (table name, column names, datatypes, case sensitivity etc)  in a couple of meta data tables. Write some dynamic SQL to read from the meta data tables to create the tables

Comment: You can't reference non-existing objects in SSDT. The only exception might be stored procedures. Other ways will be workarounds like the one you did with dummy objects. There could be tons of ways you can workaround it. SSDT project is just of XMLs and plain DDL files, so you can manipulate them as you wish. Each workaround is way unique and depends on the requirements